# How to export all rows of a WMI query to a file?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

Given a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM WIN32_PROCESS
```

1. Is there a way to interrogate the result object for the names of the columns returned?
2. Write all the rows in the result object to a text file, say

Comment: which language programming are you using?

Comment: which language are you using to make the query? WQL on VB or VC++ ?

Comment: I am using VBScript but any tips in VB.NET or C# will also help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to interrogate the result object for the names of the columns returned?

Yes. Each WMI object has the [`Properties_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393781.aspx) collection that provides information about that object's properties. To get the names of properties available in an object, enumerate the `Properties_` collection and check each item's `Name`.

> Write all the rows in the result object to a text file, say

Enumerate all the rows and use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51.aspx) to [write them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvbscript%5D+write+to+file) to the desired text file. Pseudocode:

```
create a text file and open it for writing

for each object in the result set
  for each property in the object
    write the property value to the file

close the file
```

Alternatively, you could use [`wmic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531.aspx) to do all the work for you:

```
wmic /output:e:\processes.txt process get /all
wmic /output:e:\processes.csv process get /all /format:csv
```

Comment: Thanks Helen. Using your pseudo code as a basis, I can write the names of the columns & the values - the commandline code (sample) is very useful.

Comment: for anybody who runs into this in the future, the output flag goes before the alias. wmic /output:c:\processes.csv process get /all /format:csv  and the resulting csv is not read automatically by excel, you have to specify the delimiter for it to look right..

Comment: When I use this command (on Windows 7 64-bit) I get "Invalid XSL format (or) file name." Server 2003 has the CSV format available, though. Is it possible to get CSV on Windows 7?

Comment: @PaulMoore: Works for me on Windows 7 64-bit. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9673057/113116) help?

Comment: @Helen yes, that command works, thanks. Of course, getting the syntax right in powershell (which I was using) is a nightmare, but you don't really need WMIC in powershell so that's not such an issue :-)