# wmic error (invalid XSL format) in windows7

Tags: command-line, windows-7, windows-server-2008, wmic

```
wmic process get /format:csv
```

What is wrong with this command in Windows 7?

I get:

> Invalid XSL format (or) file name.

Answer (score 12):

It's a bug in the wmic command. It's been suggested to copy XSL files into the %WINDIR%\system32 (or equivalent if 64 bit.) However, the command below works just as well without the need to copy files:

**wmic process get ProcessId,Description,CommandLine,ExecutablePath,ParentProcessId /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us\csv"**

Of course, the "en-us" will be different for different locales.

If you want to redirect output to a file add a switch **/output:"your filename here"** before the *process* keyword

Comment: I am in en-GB and it didn't have the XSL files as they were showing in the en-US directory. Using your solutions resolved it, without the need to copy files out of US to GB. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is a [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/a9beeed3-99f0-4627-ba1e-aa0161fa58c9#be9e599a-5cd8-4238-9918-df650a98c66b) in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 (also R2) WMIC. When you use (for example) Dutch regional settings in an English Windows installation, WMIC searches for the xsl files inside `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\nl-NL`, instead of `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\en-US` where they are.

Workarounds:

1. Copy or move the `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\en-US\*.xsl` files up into the `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\` folder.
2. Change your regional settings to match your Windows language version, log out and back in.
3. Specify the full path: `WMIC process get /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-US\csv"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows 7 wmic bug. Change the International setings to English (United States), reboot and test.