# wmic Invalid XSL format (or) file name. error intermittent

Tags: python, xml, wmic, moinmoin

I am getting the error randomly. Every 3rd or so time page loads no errors. Other 2/3rds of the time i get this error.

```
    ['X_Server_X on xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx - Invalid XSL format (or) file name.\r\n', 'string indices must be integers']
```

After a lot of googling and seeing other threads, the fix  of copying .xsl files to Windows/System32 doesn't seem to work. This might be because the python I am running is on moinmoin ( a wiki like page).

Also another detail, the python is calling other servers (does checks on them).

Anyone have any idea why i'm getting this error.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9673057/357313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue.

Had to move XSL files from

```
C:\Windows\system32\wbem\en-US to c:\Windows\SysWOW64  (64-bit machine).
```

Was trying to move to c:\windows\system32.

Comment: Why are you moving files into the Windows directory? You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: http://www.ctkn.net/2011/10/fix-for-windows-7-wmic-invalid-xsl-format-or-file-name/

also the code is a mess, and was only my real choice left.

Comment: Ah. This wasn't really apparent from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative fix:
Change Formats to match the C:\Windows\System32\wbem**en-US**
Control Panel > Region and Language > Formats > Format > English (United States)