# RSelenium issue with startServer() on windows 10

Tags: r, rselenium

I have an issue with RSelenium startServer() and already read the post at [RSelenium issue with startServer() on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933424/rselenium-issue-with-startserver-on-windows)

However, the solution in that thread is not working to my environment.

When I try to startServer() in R 3.3.1, I get follwoing error message.

```
Error in if (file.exists(file) == FALSE) if (!missing(asText) && asText ==  : 
   argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"wmic" path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline /format:htable' had status 4098
```

And When I try to follwoing function,

```
system2("wmic", args = c("path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline", 
                      "/format:htable"), stdout = TRUE, stderr = NULL)
```

getting this error message

```
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 4098
Warning message:
running command '"wmic" path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline /format:htable' had status 4098
```

My sessioninfo() is

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] RSelenium_1.4.0 tools_3.3.1     RCurl_1.95-4.8  RJSONIO_1.3-0   caTools_1.17.1  bitops_1.0-6    XML_3.98-1.4
```

I'm running R 3.3.1 on windows 10 and I know this error is came from windows 7 bugs related in wmic but it still makes error on windows 10

I try to move/copy the .xsl files from 
C://Windows/system32/wbem/en-US/
to 
C://windows/system32/wbem/
as another thread proposed, but it doesn't work for me.

Furthermore, When I try to run code in powershell or cmd, it shows me that there is nothing or no alias.

Funny thing is I can run correctly in my another desktop computer running windows 10. but I can't run in my windows 10 labtop computer.

I'll appreciate if yoy guys give me any suggestion.

Comment: What output is given running `wmic path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline /format:htable` in the win 10 commandline?

Comment: It says 'ERROR:Description = Not found'

Comment: Start a Selenium Server manually or use a docker container. Refer to http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843 and http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker